# how to disable didselectrowAtIndexPath when switches in tableview accessory type are ON.?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

Here is my code for disabling `didselectRowAtIndexPath` . It disables the did select row when switch is on

But when more than on switch in accessory is on  e.g. - if three switches are on and I turn off one switch , then the did select row works.

I want to disable that.

Any help ?

[image]

Here is my code.

```
     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
       {
       if (switchControl.on) {
       NSLog(@"Switch is on");
       UIAlertView *switchAlert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Switch is On" message:@"Please turn it off to proceed further" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
       [switchAlert show];
       }
        else{
        // table view did select working .
       }
```

and `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is -

```
   -(UITableViewCell*)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     {
      static NSString *cellIdentifier=@"CellID";
      UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];

          if (cell==nil)
         {
   cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];
   cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor colorWithRed:238.0/255.0 green:238.0/255.0 blue:239.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
   switchControl = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
   switchControl.tag = indexPath.row;
   cell.accessoryView = switchControl;
   [switchControl setOn:NO animated:NO];
   [switchControl addTarget:self action:@selector(switchChanged:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
}}
```

Comment: you were added the switches in tableview, if yes get the index path, if your index path is equal to selected switch then add the alert else select the row.

Comment: yes in tableviews accessory type @ Anbu.Karthik

Comment: show the screen shot of tableview

Comment: fine and simple show your cellfor row at index path method and another one doubt if you touch that the switch you want to perform this action else if you select the cell u need to perform this action.

Comment: @Saurabh : switchControl . Where did you declare this ?

Comment: @ V-Xtreme  - switchControl is declared globaly

Comment: Unless you have a fixed size table with static cells, you cannot rely on state being stored in the cell, because cells will be reused.  You need to detect when a switch in a given cell is changed and store the state of that switch in some other data structure. I would recommend an `NSIndexSet`

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik - i want that if any of my switch is on , it disables the cellForRowAtIndexPath

Comment: @ Paulw11 - How to do that?  Can u give me same code.

Comment: @Saurabh I suggest you store the `on` state in your dataSource for each cell, then you can check them in the `willSelectRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: So, to clarify; you want that if any switch is on then you can't select any row?  Or if the switch is on, then you can't select that row?

Comment: If switch is on then i can`t select any row. @ Paulw11

Answer (score 2):

Keep the array about whether the switch is on or not

Then use this delegate method

```
- (NSIndexPath * nullable)tableView:(UITableView * nonnull)tableView
       willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath * nonnull)indexPath
```

And return nil if the switch is on of this indexPath

From document

> Return Value
>
> An index-path object that confirms or alters the selected row. Return an NSIndexPath object other than indexPath if you want another cell to be selected. **Return nil if you don't want the row selected.**

Comment: It works only for one switch , if i turn on two switches and disable one of them , then the cellForRowAtIndexPath works , which **i want to disable**  @Leo

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem with your switchControl. You have to create switch control corresponding to each cell. Now from your code it seems like you are creating that universally for all the rows .The dummy code for your switch control should look like :

```
   UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath]
  if (cell.switchControl.on) {
   NSLog(@"Switch is on");
   }
    else{
   }
```

Comment: you need to cast the cell to a Custom Cell he would have defined earlier. cause the cell will be a UITableViewCell

Comment: @ Paulw11 - Yes , you r right , But i have to make uiswitch at accessory type only . I can`t create multiple switches